# Need help understanding how to work with 2D/3D glyphs

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, data-visualization

Here's the code snippet I'd like help understanding

```
for (i = 0; i < samplesX; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < samplesY; j++)
        {
            newI = DIM * i / samplesX;
            newJ = DIM * j / samplesY;
            idx = (round(newJ) * DIM) + round(newI);
            if (color_dir == 1 && draw_vecs == 1) {
                direction_to_color(vx[idx], vy[idx], color_dir);
            }
            if (color_dir == 1 && draw_vecs == 2) {
                direction_to_color(fx[idx], fy[idx], color_dir);
            }
            else if (color_dir == 2) {
                scalar = rho[idx];
                set_colormap(scalar, min, max, clampLow, clampHigh);
            }
            else if (color_dir == 3) {
                scalar = sqrt(vx[idx] * vx[idx] + vy[idx] * vy[idx]);
                set_colormap(scalar, min, max, clampLow, clampHigh);
            }
            else if (color_dir == 4) {
                scalar = sqrt(fx[idx] * fx[idx] + fy[idx] * fy[idx]);
                set_colormap(scalar, min, max, clampLow, clampHigh);
            }
            /*if (draw_vecs == 1) {
                glVertex2f(wn + (fftw_real)newI * wn, hn + (fftw_real)newJ * hn);
                glVertex2f((wn + (fftw_real)newI * wn) + vec_scale * vx[idx], (hn + (fftw_real)newJ * hn) + vec_scale * vy[idx]);
            }
            else if (draw_vecs == 2) {
                glVertex2f(wn + (fftw_real)newI * wn, hn + (fftw_real)newJ * hn);
                glVertex2f((wn + (fftw_real)newI * wn) + vec_scale * fx[idx], (hn + (fftw_real)newJ * hn) + vec_scale * fy[idx]);
            }*/
            if (draw_vecs == 1) {
                glVertex2f(wn + (fftw_real)i * wn, hn + (fftw_real)j * hn);
                glVertex2f((wn + (fftw_real)i * wn) + vec_scale * vx[idx], (hn + (fftw_real)j * hn) + vec_scale * vy[idx]);
            }
            else if (draw_vecs == 2) {
                glVertex2f(wn + (fftw_real)i * wn, hn + (fftw_real)j * hn);
                glVertex2f((wn + (fftw_real)i * wn) + vec_scale * fx[idx], (hn + (fftw_real)j * hn) + vec_scale * fy[idx]);
            }
        }
    glEnd();
}
```

What this currently does, as far as my understanding goes, is display these two-dimensional lines/arrows (hedgehogs) that visualize force/velocity in 2D as can be seen in the picture below.

[image: -]

Sadly, my understanding of linear algebra, calculus and computer graphics in general only goes so far and I'm having trouble dissecting this piece.

Ideally I'd like to understand this and also understand how I can take this pre-existing code and also add in functionality that can display two other glyph types that show a vector and/or scalar field such as

- three-dimensional cones
- three-dimensional ellipsoids

If I'm missing anything here, please let me know!

Some of the variables included in the above snippet:

```
const int DIM = 50;             //size of simulation grid
int   color_dir = 0;            //use direction color-coding or not
float scalar;
int newI, newJ;
float temp;
float vec_scale = 1000;         //scaling of hedgehogs
int   draw_vecs = 1;            //draw the vector field or not
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet you have there could have been written simpler (also it takes some educated guessing what some of the variables and functions mean).

Let's break it down.

The first two lines are easy to understand, they're the standard stanza to iterate over a 2D array

```
for (i = 0; i < samplesX; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < samplesY; j++)
```

`i` and `j` are running indices, that will iterate over every discrete coordinate tuple in `(i,j) ∈ [i, samplesX) × [j, samplesY)`. The next two lines remap the 2D indices into into a new value range, specifically `[i, samplesX)×[j, samplesY) → [0, DIM)×[0, DIM)`. A missing piece of information is, what type is `DIM` of. It would make for it to be some floating point type.

```
     newI = DIM * i / samplesX;
     newJ = DIM * j / samplesY;
```

The next line is bug prone. It translates `newI` and `newJ` into a running 1D index for a 1D array, that's addressed by `i` and `j`.

Why is this problematic? Because in the conversion to DIM-space information may have been lost. This kind of information loss may lead to **security bugs(!)**, as a matter of fact, Skia, the rendering library used by Google Chrome, Android and other projects had exactly this kind of bug recently; the writeup is a worthwhile read: https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2019/02/the-curious-case-of-convexity-confusion.html

The correct way to implement this is to have DIM be an integer and perform fixed point arithmetic on it, eventually truncating the fractional digits. But I digress. The next block is essentially performing a poor man's lookup table lookup. ``` vx``vy ``` and ``` fx``fy ``` are some flattened 2D arrays, accessed through an 1D index, and `direction_to_color` maps either to a value **presumably** to a call of `glColor`; the same probably also goes for `set_colormap`. This is a bad use of OpenGL.

The whole remapping from `i` and `j` to `DIM` and then the lookups are just poor implementation of a texture lookup. OpenGL already has textures. Just load as texture coordinate array and enable texturing.

Finally for each spine, two calls of `glVertex` are made, one with the staring point, which lies on grid centers `(wn, hn)`, to an offset location `(wn, hn) + (i, j)`.

My verdict of that code: *Utter garbage!* All of this could have been done far more elegantly, even back in 1994 with OpenGL-1.0, which is code seems to have been written for. If you want to implement your own vector field plot, don't use this as a starting point.

These days we have programmable GPUs with shaders. All of that bulk up there can be done is a few lines of shader code.

Comment: Thanks for the input and the explanation. This code was provided with the intent of us expanding on it which is why, in my case especially, I'm trying my best to refer to the original code when trying to implement new features. I'm guessing now that to iterate over a 3D variant of the aforementioned code snippet we'd have to cycle through a 3D array? Or is there an easier/more proper solution to implement 3D glyphs?

Comment: @K.Saudi: Is this a class assignment? If so, complain to your school that you're taught severely outdated knowledge, which today is irrelevant outside of maintaining legacy codebases. Anyway, if they ask for 3D spines, do they want it in a 3D grid, or shall the spines be pointing in 3D, but still be on a 2D grid. Technically it doesn't really matter, because 2D is equal to 3D with the 3rd dimension extent set to 1. As for how to do it: For every `…x` and `…y` you'd introduce another `…z` and add and third index. After `i` and `j` comes __`k`__, so that would be suitable name.